# Will SpaceX Starship have launch abort system?

Tags: spacex, launch, interplanetary, spacex-starship, abort

Since future SpaceX Starship is planned as long duration passenger spacecraft for multiplanetary transport will it have launch abort system? Also how is crew evacuation planned during interplanetary flights and how during ascent from Moon, Mars?

Comment: Current knowledge seems to indicate no abort/eject for crew yet. But no crew vehicle has even begun development so this is very likely to change severely as time progresses.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6lPMFgZU5Q great video on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will almost certainly be required to have one for the terrestrial portion. Consider that both SpaceX's Crew Dragon and Boeing's Starliner have been required to have an in-flight abort test. I can't see NASA (or the forthcoming Space Command) skipping out on what are considered standard safety systems *now*.

> Also how is crew evacuation planned during interplanetary flights and how during ascent from Moon, Mars?

This part is a bit trickier. It's easy to demand one for systems we already have, but you're talking about launching, landing and then potentially using on Mars. To date, nobody has sent something to Mars and then had it lift off again. While it would be nice to have in-flight abort here as well, that may not be feasible. None of the Apollo lunar landers had in-flight abort either.

Comment: If you need an abort at/leaving Mars, you are probably not leaving for a LONG while, so an abort system wouldn't really help much.  Consider the Apollo LEM, which also did not have a launch abort system.

Comment: Do NASA and/or Space Command have regulatory approval over this?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's not entirely clear. [The current regulatory laws have not kept pace](https://www.politico.com/news/2019/12/25/space-tourists-safety-rules-089681), but my assumption is that if SpaceX starts shooting private folks into space, sooner or later the regulatory regime will follow. So if they're going to regulate this, my bet is it will be NASA/SC doing so. All it will take is one mishap for the American public to demand it.

Comment: @Machavity today commercial human spaceflight is regulated by the FAA to whatever extent it is regulated.  Your answer seems to be informed speculation, at best.

Comment: I was assuming the intent of Starship was to be reliable enough not to need abort systems, much like airplanes. I dont think they want starship to be used for NASA at least at some point.

Comment: It could very well be, but I expect the two-stage portion will simply have a way to abort with its own engines. I doubt the actual Starship portion will have a way to abort anywhere else it lands.

Comment: Please note that the Space Shuttle did not have an abort system either.

Comment: @JohnEye Like escape motors? No. But the shuttle was a giant glider and could be used as an escape system. After the Challenger explosion, the Flight Director was actively hoping to see the orbiter emerge so they could glide to an abort site.